# Junit 4 global setup and teardown

Tags: java, testing, junit

i want a separate class with `setup` and `teardown` for my entire tests.
i managed to crate a class that do that (its a bit tricky, hope there is a better way...).

but when running a specific test from intellij (right click on the file), the setup class is not called.

this is my setup class

```
public class BaseTest extends TestCase {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseTest.class);

   @Override
   protected void setUp() throws Exception {
       ///Some setup code ...

   }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //Put teardown code here 
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodA() {} // For some reason i must add this method, for my code to run

}
```

Comment: Why don't use Before and After annotations?

Comment: can you provide an example, Before,After all of test classes  ?

Comment: Hello Shay,Hope my answer helped you .If yes please accept the answer if not please let me know so that I can improvise on that and help you to give  a better solution.

Comment: i wanted a single place for setup and tear down, for the entire test.
currently I'm using my own JunitRunner in order to do so .
so before each test dose not helping much. i think answering my own question will be fair for other users

Comment: You can create a parent class wherein you can write your methods like setup and teardown and extend this class among all your subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class BaseTest extends TestCase {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseTest.class);

    @Before
       protected void setUp() throws Exception {
           ///Some setup code ...

       }

    @After
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //Put teardown code here 
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodA() {} // For some reason i must add this method, for my code to run

}
```

Comment: You need to run as junit test and one more thing you don't need to extend Testcase also.It works without it.

Comment: I haven't used intellij .I beleave the logic will remain same whether it's IDEA or eclipse.Try removing extend s and run the test class .If it gets success then you r good.